# Can a returned struct be overwritten?

Tags: c, struct, scope, return-value

I have a struct that is returned by some function:

```
struct Abc {
    char *a;
    int b;
};

static struct Abc foo() {
    struct Abc mystruct;
    mystruct.a = "asdf";
    mystruct.b = 1;

    return mystruct;
}
```

If I call `struct Abc new_abc = foo();`, is it possible for the struct stored in `new_abc` to be overwritten by the program?

If I understand correctly, `mystruct` is an automatic variable which is local in scope. Thus the reference might be left dangling and hence can be overwritten.

Comment: Formally there are no *references* in C. If you were referring to pointers, then have close look and see that the code you show does not use pointers.

Comment: There isn't any difference in how `int x = bar();` and `struct Abc y = foo();` work. They both copy the value returned by the function into the variable. Variables and parameter values are always copied in C, i.e. `a = b;` always means copy the contents of `b` into `a`. Note that in case of pointers, contents of the variable is the address, which is a number, again simply copied from one place to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *If I call `struct Abc new_abc = foo();`, is it possible for the struct stored in `new_abc` to be overwritten by the program?*

Yes, `new_abc` is just another variable. It can be overwritten is the program(mer) wishes so.

> *If I understand correctly, `mystruct` is an automatic variable which is local in scope. Thus the reference might be left dangling and hence can be overwritten.*

You are not returning the address of the local variable, you're returning the value. Returning a structure variable is functionally same as returning a local `int` or `char`. There's no dangling pointer here.

---

EDIT:

As clarified in the comments:

*"will it ever be overwritten by the program allocating memory for other things"*

The answer is no. You're returning the value and storing it in a variable. Sure, if you create too many local variables, you may face stack overflow, but the allocated memory for a automatic local variable (which is used to store the returned value) will not be *claimed back* unless it goes out of scope.

In other words, once the value of the local variable is returned from the function and stored in another variable in the caller, the local variable in the function need no exist anymore to be able access the stored value in the caller.

Comment: Hi sorry for the misunderstanding, but I meant "will it ever be overwritten by the program allocating memory for other things?", not whether it can be overwritten in the code.

Comment: @JamesTan No, it won;t

Comment: @JamesTan do you mean in case you call foo() again? If you do so, every time you call it it will create a new local struct to hold the value, then return this value like Sourav said, so I also don't see any potential problems

Comment: @JamesTan Just updated my answer for some more clarity.